# How do I use multiple comparison operators in a keyed array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a custom post type for events, and trying to display events happening between now and 30 days from now. Pulling all the dates correctly, but I can't seem to get a *range* of dates into my comparison operators. Here's where I am:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'post_type'         => 'event',
'meta_query'        => array(
    array(
        'key'           => 'event_date',
        'compare'       => '<',
        'value'         => $nextMonthDate,
        'type'          => 'DATETIME'
            )
),
'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
'order'             => 'ASC',
'meta_key'          => 'event_date',
'meta_type'         => 'DATETIME'
));
```

I also have a `$date_now` variable. Essentially I need an `if (event_date >= $date_now && event_date < $nextMonthDate)`, but in this array, which I apparently need to use to pull other post data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple `meta_query` conditions as well. I think the following following snippet will help you achieve your expected filter. But didn't test it

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'event',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'           => 'event_date',
            'value'         => $now,
            'type'          => 'DATETIME',
            'compare'       => '>=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'           => 'event_date',
            'value'         => $nextMonthDate,
            'type'          => 'DATETIME',
            'compare'       => '<',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'          => 'event_date',
    'meta_type'         => 'DATETIME',
));
```

Note the `$now` I used, just pass on the current date there.

**Extra**
I think you can also use `BETWEEN` as compare operator and pass on an array of two items where first one is min and second one is maximum. I am not sure if this will work with `DATETIME` type or not but it surely does work with `NUMERIC` types.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'event',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'           => 'event_date',
            'value'         => array( $now, $nextMonthDate ),
            'type'          => 'DATETIME'
            'compare'       => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'          => 'event_date',
    'meta_type'         => 'DATETIME',
));
```

Comment: That did it, thank you!!! Needed a couple extra commas but worked like a charm. I didn't know the `relation => 'AND'` thing, that's great.

Comment: @NickWritesMusic I think hitting the documentation is always the best way to solve an issue. [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the commas. I added the missing commas so that this might not be an issue for anyone in the future.